# window DeviceMotion event using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devicemotion

I'm not able to trigger the `DeviceMotion` function in React app when I move my browser. I'm using `window` object `devicemotion` event to achieve the functionality.

Excerpt from my code

```
export default function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState("");
  const [y, setY] = useState("");
  const [z, setZ] = useState("");

  function handleMotionEvent(event) {
    console.log("handle motion event", event);

    var x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
    var y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
    var z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;

    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setZ(z);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("devicemotion", handleMotionEvent, true);
  }, [x, y, z]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Device Motion</h1>
      <div>
        X - {x} Y - {y} Z - {z}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-grass-b90vc?file=/src/App.js:0-734). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using SSL cert, you have to set your react App to use an SSL cert, the instructions can be found in this link https://www.makeuseof.com/create-react-app-ssl-https/ once you run with the SSL cert your mobile browser will read de accelerometers data, I hope this help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32632141)